# Перегрузка оператора = для своего итератора

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Доброго времени суток. Имеется свой вложенный класс-итератор(главный класс - шаблонный). Имеются методы разыменования и присвоения разыменованного значения. Вот прототипы:

```
 class Iterator
{
    T* element;
    Iterator();
public:
    Iterator(T* m) :element(m) {};
    Iterator(const Iterator&);
    Iterator& operator=(const Iterator&);
    Iterator& operator=(T); // присвоение нового значения
    Iterator& operator++();
    bool operator!=(const Iterator&);
    T operator*(); // разыменование
};
```

Такая запись возможна(то есть значение из last помещается в first):

```
 first = *last
```

А как реализовать такую?

```
 *first = *last
```

Заранее спасибо. Для чего нужно? Просто интересуюсь.

Comment: `first = *last` для двух итераторов - это довольно "странный" синтаксис. Зачем он вам такой понадобился? Зачем вы ввели этот `Iterator& operator=(T);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это никакого отношения к оператора присваивания итератора не имеет отношения.

Вам надо объявить и определить в классе итератора оператор разыменования `operator *` в виде

```
T & operator*();
```

То есть нужно возвращать ссылку на объект, чтобы можно было ему сделать присвоение.

Comment: Точно. Забыл про ссылку..спасибо, вопрос решён.